# How do I make the program continuously run?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a rock paper scissors game(I purposefully left out some parts of the code, just to make things easier understand), and I want to be able to keep the game going after the button is pressed once. The way the game is set up now, once you press the button, the game will tell whether you've won or you've lost. At that point if you try to press the button again, nothing happens. I've been experimenting with several different methods, but I can't seem to find a way to do it. If someone can help me make it so that after the first click if I click the button again, the game is able to continue going with the computer picking a new choice, and so on, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
const choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
const computersChoice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
const rockButton = document.getElementById("rockbtn");
const updateText = document.getElementById('textField')
let yourChoice
let status
let statusComp


//function for when user clicks rock button
function userRock() {
    rockButton.addEventListener ("click", function() {
        yourChoice = choices[0]  
        execute()
  });
}

function execute(){
    checker()
    computersTurn()
}

// checks to see if user made a choice
function checker(){
    if (yourChoice === choices[0]) {
        status ='rock'
    }
  }  

// computer chooses
function computersTurn() {
        statusComp = computersChoice
        //logs check to make sure the program is running correctly
        console.log(status)
        console.log(statusComp)
        if (status === statusComp) {
            updateText.innerText = 'It\s a tie'
        } else if (status === 'rock' && statusComp === 'paper'){
            updateText.innerText = 'You lose... Computer chose paper'
        } else if (status === 'rock' && statusComp === 'scissors'){
            updateText.innerText = 'You win... Computer chose scissors'
        }
  }


function startGame(){
    userRock()

}

startGame()
```

Comment: can you show us your HTML as well?

Comment: To make the program run endlessly you need something called recursion, if you google it, you'll have your answer.

Comment: A loop is typically used for this case.

Comment: while(exitCondition)  ?

Comment: Can you share a whole (not) working code, to reproduce your issue. Because here I don't see why the click would be triggered only once. If it is your issue, a loop would not solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are getting computerChoice just once. You should get the computer choice on every click.

```js
const choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
let computersChoice ;
const rockButton = document.getElementById("rockbtn");
const updateText = document.getElementById('textField')
let yourChoice
let status
let statusComp


//function for when user clicks rock button
function userRock() {
    rockButton.addEventListener ("click", function() {
        yourChoice = choices[0];
        computersChoice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
        execute()
  });
}

function execute(){
    checker()
    computersTurn()
}

// checks to see if user made a choice
function checker(){
    if (yourChoice === choices[0]) {
        status ='rock'
    }
  }  

// computer chooses
function computersTurn() {
        statusComp = computersChoice
        //logs check to make sure the program is running correctly
        console.log(status)
        console.log(statusComp)
        if (status === statusComp) {
            updateText.innerText = 'It\s a tie'
        } else if (status === 'rock' && statusComp === 'paper'){
            updateText.innerText = 'You lose... Computer chose paper'
        } else if (status === 'rock' && statusComp === 'scissors'){
            updateText.innerText = 'You win... Computer chose scissors'
        }
  }


function startGame(){
    userRock()

}

startGame()
```

```html
<button id="rockbtn">Play</button>
<span id="textField"/></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple. Just move the one line where you create the computers choice to your `computerTurns()` function. This way the computer doesn't use the same result all the time. Everything else can stay the same and will work.

```js
const choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
const rockButton = document.getElementById("rockbtn");
const updateText = document.getElementById('textField')
let computersChoice;
let yourChoice
let status
let statusComp


//function for when user clicks rock button
function userRock() {
    rockButton.addEventListener ("click", function() {
        yourChoice = choices[0]  
        execute()
  });
}

function execute(){
    checker()
    computersTurn()
}

// checks to see if user made a choice
function checker(){
    if (yourChoice === choices[0]) {
        status ='rock'
    }
  }  

// computer chooses
function computersTurn() {
        computersChoice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
        statusComp = computersChoice
        //logs check to make sure the program is running correctly
        console.log(status)
        console.log(statusComp)
        if (status === statusComp) {
            updateText.innerText = 'It\s a tie'
        } else if (status === 'rock' && statusComp === 'paper'){
            updateText.innerText = 'You lose... Computer chose paper'
        } else if (status === 'rock' && statusComp === 'scissors'){
            updateText.innerText = 'You win... Computer chose scissors'
        }
  }


function startGame(){
    userRock()

}

startGame()
```

```html
<button id="rockbtn">Rock</button>
<textarea id="textField"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't realize there was such a simple solution. I'm extremely grateful for your insight.

Comment: You are welcome :) You should consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my or @AnkitChaudhary answer by clicking on the tick below the votes on the top left. This way the system closes the question (it doesn't appear for others anymore). You will also receive reputation for this.